# Angular routing acting strange when url is manually typed

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes

I'm building a web app using Angular 7 for the frontend and NodeJS, MongoDB and ExpressJS for the backend. The application runs as intended as long as I interact with the application to navigate, but when I manually type the path, it seems like it doesn't hit the component for the route. It works all good locally, but not on Heroku.

Here's is my app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [{ 
  path: "login", 
  component : LoginComponent
  },
  {
  path: "registration", 
  component : SignupComponent
  },
  {
    path: "votes", 
    component : VotesComponent
  },
  {
    path: "votes/:website", 
    component : VoteComponent
  },
  { 
    path: "**", 
    redirectTo: "votes" 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: false})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

All my routes in Express is prefixed with /api/, such as:

```
app.get('/api/votes', (req, res, next) => {
  const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit)
  db.getVotes(limit).then((votes) => {
    res.json(votes);
});
```

});

I check the jwt like this:

```
app.use(
    checkJwt({ secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET }).unless({ path: [ 
              { url: "/api/authenticate", methods: ['POST'] }, 
              { url: "/api/votes", methods: ["GET"]}]})
);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Not authorized.' });
    };
});
```

My call to votes is performed like this:

```
private baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/votes`, this.httpOptions))).subscribe(data => {
       this.data = data;
});
```

The baseUrl is defined as follows in the evironment.prod.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: '/api'
};
```

Here comes the problem. If I go to my deployment on Heroku and access https://myurl.com I'm redirected to https://myurl.com/votes and I can see the requested url is https://myurl.com/api/votes, so thats all fine and I get my angular application with all the data. But if I manually type in https://myurl.com/votes I get JSON back in the browser with error "Not authorized", and I can see that the requested URL is https://myurl.com/votes, instead of https://myurl.com/api/votes. Any ideas whats causing this? It seems like Angular is not routing it properly. When it's typed manually it doesn't hit any of my components.

Answer (score 0):

For non-match route path, the router configuration should include below one.

```
{ 
    path: "", 
    component: "404NotFoundComponent" 
}
```

Comment: Thats noted, but that doesn't explain my problem. The route should exist and does it when I use the controls, but not when I type the url manually.

Comment: Can you tel us how you are configuring the internal url redirect 'api/votes'.

Comment: As an example I do this: routerLink="/votes/{{vote.websiteUrl}}, and it works all great. The /api-prefix is only for calling the backend.

Comment: When I run it locally I use a proxy-file: {
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false
    }
}